# Looping through XML table blocks with BeautifulSoup in Python

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I have a data structure as so when parsing some XML with beautiful soup:

```
<h2>Fri 4 May</h2><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="12">

            <tr>

                <td class="time ">6:00am</td>  

                <td class="other-details ">

                    <a class="prog-link" href="http://www.tvguide.co.uk/m-detail/157702075/137913159/breakfast" id="308829348" >

                        <div class="title" style="border-left:4px solid #CE3D32">

                            Breakfast

                        </div>

                        <div class="detail">

                        A round-up of national and international news, plus current affairs, arts and entertainment, and weather   

                            <div class="other">

                            (Subtitles) (Interactive) 

                            </div>

                            <br>





                                    <div class="rating">Rating:  <span class="rating-num">1.5</span></div>



                        </div>

                    </a>

                </td>

            </tr>
...
...
...
</table>
```

There are several of these structures in chronological date order that has TV guide data for consecutive days.

The code I have at the minute is like so:

```
for x in soup.select('h2'):

                for tr in soup.select('table tr'):

                    if not tr.script:

                        for td in tr.find_all('td'):

                            a = ''.join(re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', td.text))
                            b = a.strip()

                            #print x.text
                            #print b

                            if b[:1] in '0123456789':


                                date_list.append(b)


                            else:

                                if ' Rating' in b:

                                    c = b.split(' Rating')

                                else:

                                    c = b.split(' Rating')
                                    c.append(0.0)

                                desc = c[0]
                                desc_list.append(desc)


                                rating = ''.join(['Rating: ', str(c[1])])
                                rating_list.append(rating)
```

However, this is giving me every single  block across all possible dates for EVERY date instance as defined in the `<h2>` tag. What I actually want in logical order is:

1. Interate through each `<h2>` date tag in order.
2. Print only the `<table>` block belonging to that day.

I'm nearly there, just cant figure out the final amendment I need to make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue could be that "soup.select" always starts from the beginning of your XML, and thus in your second soup.select you are finding all instances of tr.

In this following snipped I've replaced the second soup.select with x.select - that will then only do the select from the "x" node rather than from the beginning.

```
for x in soup.select('table'):

                for tr in x.select('tr'):
```

Comment: hi, thanks for replying. this is not working, unless i have misunderstood something. the ,h2> tag is closed off with a </h2> before the <table> is defined. so therefore, if my limited knowledge of XML is correct, having a loop within the first soup.select referencing <h2> will return nothing...

Comment: Ah, ok, yes correct- the <h2> does not have any children. I've modified the code above to first select the <table> and then, select the <tr> within the table.

Comment: so is 'for x in soup.select('h2'): no longer needed then?

Comment: That's correct. That will only select the h2 node, and since that has no children, you won't be able to traverse the tree under it. However if select the parent table nodes (assuming you may want to put a class to it), then you can iterate over its children in each loop.

Comment: ok, so that loop worked as i wanted...the final bit i need, is that i do also need to grab the date value with <h2> as the revised nested loop iterates. if i was to put something like 'date = soup.find('h2').text' within the outer level of the next loop, would that give me the date per pass as well?

Comment: actually found a way to what i want by using soup.find_all('h2') outside the first level of the loop, the setting a variable to be the first item in the list object that find_all() generates, then popping the first item in said dictionary as the code loops through. thanks for your help with the rest of it though!